# In R, what can a data.table column store? Simple examples please

Tags: r, data.table

Data.table package is amazing. I know I can store a vector in a column. That vector can be strings or numbers. I know I [can store lists](http://brooksandrew.github.io/simpleblog/articles/advanced-data-table/#columns-of-lists).

What else can I store? I recall that I could store models, data.tables, xml documents in a data.table. Am I confabulating? I fear I am since I am having a hard time finding straight-forward resources telling me how to store and manipulate these objects in a data.table.

Comment: data.table(plot = plot(1)) doesn't work

Comment: In general, anything that is easily serialized can be put into a `list` which can be set as a column. Raw blobs can be. While @Waldi's point is technically true, you can insert recorded plots; try `plot(1)` and then `data.table(a=1, r=list(recordPlot()))`. It might not be convenient in this example, but it can be done. (Can't seem to get it to work with `data.frame` yet ...

Comment: Note, though, that just because you can *store* something in a list-column doesn't mean that you can properly use it. For instance, anything with ties to C objects (e.g., pointers) *cannot* be reused in new processes; `dput(data.table())` cannot be reused in a new R instance as-is because of the `.internal.selfref=` ref. Database connection objects from `DBI` also cannot. So while one might be able to store these objects in a `data.table`, if you `saveRDS` and `readRDS` that file in a new R, it won't work.

Comment: @r2evans Your point that just because one can does not mean one can actually use it. Do you have a url that gives examples of **useful** items stored in data.table columns?

Comment: Farrel, nope, not really. In the tidyverse landscape, there are plenty of packages that use columns to store regression models, summaries, predictions ... `tidymodels` comes to mind, though I don't use it (atm). I think the utility of list-columns becomes much more apparent when (for example) using `magrittr::%>%` and making code read top-to-bottom instead of inside-out. That doesn't mean they're only useful there, but I find that a useful construct for code organization.

Answer (score 4):

Most types are valid through `data.table()` but the range of well-supported classes is narrower. Mostly, to keep anything in a `data.table` you can put it in a `list` column.

Note that not all `data.table` operations are supported for all types, however.

To wit, we only offer sorting for atomic types (see `?is.atomic`). Sorting is the workhorse behind grouping `by=` and joins (`on=` / `merge`), so if your grouping column or is a `list`, you're out of luck. Joining using `complex` columns is also not supported.

Please feel free to report to our [issue tracker](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues) with use cases of anything that's not supported.

Comment: I seen handling complex type inside `bmerge`, so maybe it is supported but just disabled?

Comment: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/3690 @jangorecki IIRC the support for complex is just about columns in the output, not the columns used to join, see `DT = data.table(a = 1:5, z = 6:10 + (5:1)*1i); DT[DT, on = 'a']; DT[DT, on = 'z']` the join on `integer` with `complex` result works, but the join on `complex` with `integer` result fails